# Use of undeclared type 'cocoapods library'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I made a pod [Here](https://github.com/theduman/TDTextSlider) and pushed cocoapods succesfully. When I try to test my library I added

```
pod 'TDTextSlider'
```

to my podfile of another test project.It is installed and imported without error but when I try to use the library with this code

```
let td : TDTextSlider = TDTextSlider(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

I got "Use of undeclared type TDTextSlider" error but when I copy the swift.class manually its working.What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you import it in that file? `import TDTextSlider`

Comment: Yes i did. XCode recognized the module TDTextSlider when I imported but when I try to use It gives me that error.

Comment: The last time I encountered the same error was because I opened the xcode project file instead of the xcode workspace file.

Comment: @HongWei I tried many times I am sure I am opening my project with .xcworkspace file

Comment: Please share your podfile.

Comment: @Ujjwal-Nadhani https://justpaste.it/11yxz

Comment: and the library code https://justpaste.it/11yy7

Comment: class should be `open` or `public`
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

Comment: @zepar I installed on fresh test project and tried to clean and deleted derived data.Maybe problem is about the library itself.

Comment: @zepar Thank you so much my friend.You are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the classes you are trying to access are public or Open.